# Printing array contents in the same line in awk

Tags: arrays, shell, awk

I have a script where I need to print the array contents in the same line of the previous print statement. Here `array is dynamic in size` and I have already one print statement which shows column wise output.

For example: let array having 3 contents (arr[1]=2,arr[2]=4,arr[3]=6), min=100, max=200. I have print statement which is printing column wise result.

```
gawk '{
  ...
  ...
print "Min:" min "\tMax:" max 
for (itr in arr)
print arr[i] " "

}' script.txt
```

Expected Output:

```
Min:100  Max:200  2 4 6
```

My output:

```
Min:100 Max:200
2
4
6
```

Please suugest me an approach, how to append the array contents in previous print result.

Comment: `for (itr in arr)
print arr[i]` is definitely NOT producing that output (`i` vs `itr`). Show us a [mcve] if you'd like help.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try using echo it has `-n` option to skip printing newline at the end.

```
gawk '{
  ...
  ...
echo -n "Min:" min "\tMax:" max 
for (itr in arr)
echo -n arr[i] " "

}' script.sh
```

**Another Approach**

```
gawk '{
  ...
  ...
printf "Min:" min "\tMax:" max 
for (itr in arr)
printf arr[i] " "

}' script.sh
```

Please refer [echo](https://ss64.com/bash/echo.html) documentation.

Comment: After  replacing print with `echo -n`, I can not see any output.

Comment: Check another approach to do the same.

Comment: Yes, It is happening.Thanks!!

Comment: This is absolutely wrong. `echo` is a shell command, not an awk one, so `echo -n "Min:"` means `concatenate the string contained in the variable named n with the string "Min:" then convert that to a number before subtracting it from the value contained in the variable named echo`. Hence no output. At least `printf` IS an awk command but you should never use it the way it's shown in this answer as it's puting the input data where the format string should be and so will fail cryptically if/when the input contains formatting chars. It will also leave a trailing blank and no terminating newline.